# ABE Attributes Based Encryption

Tags: encryption

I have a question .
How the system know the attributes of the users to be after that as a public key in ABE?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your question. It does not appear to be grammatically correct. Can you provide more context?

Comment: Also please be clear on whether you are asking about CP-ABE or KP-ABE.